# Battery Issues in new laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, battery-life

I just got a new ASUS laptop yesterday and now it seems to have battery issues. I was allowing a few updates to download and install in the "Windows Updates" settings.

When the updates were downloading and getting ready(few of them got installed itself), the laptop screen blinked a few times, the typical USB interface plugged-in and off sounds played a few times, then the battery percentage which was at 52% dropped to 0% suddenly. It was then followed by an emergency shutdown.

I plugged in my laptop and booted it up again and it was normal. To investigate what had happened I installed the HWMonitor and checked the battery status. I saw that the battery had halved in its maximum charging capacity(coincidence? I think not).

I generated a Battery-Report from the Command-Prompt to investigate more and I couldn't find what went wrong from it either. Here are pages from the report,

[image: Page 0]

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

[image: Page 3]

Laptop Specifications,

OS: Windows 10 64bit

Processor: i7 9750H

RAM: 16GB

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX1650

VRAM: 4GB

Storage: 1TB SSD

What could be the problem? How to solve this?

Comment: This obviously shouldn’t happen on a brand new laptop, you likely have a bad battery. I suggest you contact Asus and invoke your warranty. You could try a full discharge / charge cycle first.

Comment: @JamesP That's one sure shot solution. I thought about it too, but then I want to know what problem I might be facing currently if it just isn't the case of a bad battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asus Support will probably ask you first to
[calibrate your battery](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1032745/),
by filling it up to 100% and draining to 0%.

Follow the procedure in the above Asus link, where you can use perhaps
a repeating video to drain the battery faster.

After the battery calibration, if the problem remains, you will have a case
for demanding an exchange under warranty.

Another tool you can use is in Windows *Settings > System > Battery*, where you
can trace battery usage to see if some app is using it heavily.